# Atheros AR5008 not working properly

Tags: 11.10, wireless

On Ubuntu 10.04 server 32bit it worked on 20dBm/100mW, but on 11.10 it just can use 17dBm/50mW. Why? How can I use this wireless card on 11.10 as I used it on 10.04?

Comment: Which regulatory domain are you in (i.e. which country)? For example, in Japan you're not allowed to transmit over 50mW (if I'm not mistaken). You can check which regulatory domain Ubuntu put you in with this command in the terminal: `grep CRDA /var/log/kern.log`.

Comment: Which driver is the card using ath5k or ath9k?

Answer (score 1):

From what I am reading there are issues with this card and the newer ath9k driver the kernel is using.

Suggestions that have been made are:

This one is the one I have seen the most and the one people claim worked the most. I do not have your card so I can not test.
create

> /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf

then add the following line:

> options ath9k nohwcrypt=1

another suggestion is:

> echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/ieee80211/phy0/ath9k/disable_ani

Comment: didn't helped, sorry

Comment: I have not seen any other suggestions, but there are many reported issues about this. My hope is that it will be addressed in future kernel releases.